How to use Secure Erase with "hdparm"?
I am lately trying to learn the secure erase feature. My goal is to use secure erase in windows. I searched for tools and found out that hdparm is a perfect solution.
I tried to use hdparm but in the tutorials it says that before you start the erase process you must put the drive to "Not Frozen" state. There are solutions for this in Linux but I couldn't find any solutions in Windows.
Is there a hdparm secure erase tutorial for Windows users or does any of you know what to do?
